# Symfony2, Sonata : Collapsed group

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I've been trying to do something relatively simple but that does not work.

I want to be able to collapse groups in sonata to enhance the user's experience.

```
->with('MyGroup', array('collapsed' => true))
    -add('MyField')
->end();
```

This is based on the Sonata [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/defining_admin_class.html).

Pretty simple but i can't see why it does not work.
Does array('collapsed' => true) is not enough?

Is it an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collapsed option seems to have been removed in the latest version of Sonata :

- in 2.1 it is available
  https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.1/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig#L21
- in 2.2 and latest it is not, there is only one reference of collapsed
  in the file, which is for a css class. https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.2/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig#L41

Changelog 2.2 :  https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md

Comment: Ha that's so bad. I'll see if i can style the groups. Thank you so much for your time ;) .

Comment: that answered my questions too. Too bad it was removed :(