# How to make sub groups in sonata admin form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

In Sonata's `AdminBundle\Mapper\BaseGroupedMapper.php`, I saw a code example:

```
    public function with($name, array $options = array())
    {
    /*
     * The current implementation should work with the following workflow:
     *
     *     $formMapper
     *        ->with('group1')
     *            ->add('username')
     *            ->add('password')
     *        ->end()
     *        ->with('tab1', array('tab' => true))
     *            ->with('group1')
     *                ->add('username')
     *                ->add('password')
     *            ->end()
     *            ->with('group2', array('collapsed' => true))
     *                ->add('enabled')
     *                ->add('createdAt')
     *            ->end()
     *        ->end();
     *
     */
```

Unfortunately, I get an error if I add a group first and THEN add tabs. I want my form to have a main simple form (firstname, etc...), and then tabs  under it to list the entity relation forms (onetomany...) tab by tab to keep it clean. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
New tab was added automatically when you have added field or group. You should close current tab before adding new one OR add tabs before adding groups and fields.
```

Does anyone know how to make this work ? Or this was 2 separated examples? I would like if possible to avoid having pure tabs and therefore not being able to have a part of my form constantly visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use tabs all your element must be between tabs.

In your example you are missing a tab between the first group1, you should do this :

```
$formMapper
    ->tab('General')
        ->with('group1')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
        ->end()
    ->end()
    ->tab('Relations')
        ->with('group1')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
        ->end()
        ->with('group2')
            ->add('enabled')
            ->add('createdAt')
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Instead of using `->with('', array('tab' => true)` I used `->tab('')`, makes more sense.

Also collapsed is no more supported : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105992/3726645

Documentation : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_create_edit.html#formgroup-options